# Someone else is experiencing an infinite "Waiting" with new iOS 11.4.1?

Tags: ios, installation, infinite, google-fabric, fabric.io

I recently registered a new app at Fabric.io, invited my test team, added their UDID at my developer account, downloaded the provisioning profile with the devices included and followed all steps as I am used to execute.

Everything seems fine, but in time to install my app, the icon appears at home screen from my team phones, but never goes to another status as loading or installed the app. The most curious thing, if you go to user status there appears as the user installed it.

Someone with same problem? The unique common stuff I saw is the operational system, it seems to be a kinda new problem.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Make sure that you're launching the app via the Beta app for those states to update.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Yes. I just did what you said and it worked. **Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. In order for Beta to accurately track the status of your testers, they need to launch the app from the Beta app. Once they do that, their status will go to "Installed" within the Beta dashboard.